# How can I prove that $2/9<x^4+y^4<8$?

Tags: inequality

$x$ and $y$ are real numbers.

Given that $1<x^2-xy+y^2<2$, how can I show that $\frac 29<x^4+y^4<8$ ?

Then can I use that to prove that for any natural number $n>3$

$$x^{2^n}+y^{2^n}>\frac 2{3^{2^n}} \text{?}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) to show $x^4+y^4 < 8$, you already have a good solution by squaring $x^2+y^2<2+xy$.

2) By AM-GM and Cauchy Schwarz, we get

$$\left(x^4+y^4+\frac{x^4+y^4}2\right)(3) \ge (x^4+y^4+x^2y^2)(1^2+1^2+(-1)^2) \ge (x^2+y^2-xy)^2 > 1$$
hence $x^4+y^4 > \frac29$

For the more general case, you could use Power Means in addition to the above, i.e. for $n>2$:
$$\sqrt[2^n]{\frac{x^{2^n}+y^{2^n}}2} \ge \sqrt[4]{\frac{x^4+y^4}2} > \frac1{\sqrt3} \implies x^{2^n}+y^{2^n} > \frac2{3^{2^{n-1}}}$$
which is a tighter bound than your inequality.

Comment: Great solution. could you just expand your solution into clear steps?

Comment: @Arashium don't think I have skipped steps, let me know what's unclear, I will expand that.

Comment: How did you apply Cauchy Schwarz?

Comment: @Arashium CS is used in the step $(x^4+y^4+x^2y^2)(1^2+1^2+(-1)^2)\ge(x^2+y^2-xy)^2$.

Comment: @Macavity How do you get $\sqrt[4]{\frac{x^4+y^4}2} > \frac1{\sqrt3}$

Comment: @Greninja using $x^4+y^4>\frac29$

Answer (score 3):

$x^2 - xy + y^2 = 1$ is an ellipse. to find out the minor and major axis, we change variables $$x = \xi \cos t - \eta \sin t, y = \xi \sin t + \eta \cos t$$ where $t$ will be determined later.

the ellipse in $\xi, \eta$ coordinates is $$\xi^2(\cos^2 t -\sin t \cos t+\sin^2 t) + \xi \eta(-2\cos t \sin t+\sin^2 t - \cos^2 t+2\sin t \cos t) + \eta^2(\sin ^2 t +\sin t \cos t +\cos ^2 t) =1 $$

set $t = \frac{\pi}{4},$ you get $$\frac12\xi ^2+\frac32\eta^2= 1. $$

so the major and minor axis of the ellipse $x^2 - xy + y^2 = 1$ are 
$\sqrt 2$ and $ \sqrt { \frac23}.$

therefore by symmetry the minimum of$x^4 + y^4$ on the hyperbola $x^2 -xy + y^2 = 1$ is achieved on the minor axis $x = -\sqrt\frac13, y = \sqrt \frac 13$ and the minimum value is $\dfrac{2}{9}.$

therefore by symmetry the minimum of$x^4 + y^4$ on the hyperbola $x^2 -xy + y^2 = 2$ is achieved on the major axis $x = \sqrt 2, y = \sqrt 2$ and the maximum value is $8.$

we have established $$ \dfrac{2}{9} \le x^4 + y^4 \le 8 \text { on } 1 \le x^2 - xy + y^2 \le 2.$$

Answer (score 3):

$0\leq x^2+y^2<2+xy$. Squaring it, you get $x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2<4+4xy+x^2y^2\Rightarrow x^4+y^4<4+4xy-x^2y^2=8-(4+x^2y^2-4xy)=8-(2-xy)^2\leq 8$

Comment: The main problem is how to use the other side $1<x^2-xy+y^2$. I tried and got no result except for $x^2+y^2<\frac13$

Comment: I tried to distinguish between the cases $xy+1<0$ and $xy+1\geq 0$ and squaring the inequality. I do not think $x^2+y^2<1/3$, take $x=3/2$, $y=1$.

Comment: oops, my mistake $x^2+y^2>\frac13$ and $xy>-\frac23$. The $xy>-\frac23$ comes from $0<x^2+y^2+2xy<2+3xy$