# $x$ and $y$ are two real numbers such that: $1 \leq x^2 + y^2 - xy \leq 2$ Show that: $\frac{2}{9} \leq x^4 + y^4 \leq 8$

Tags: inequality

I know that the question was posted here somewhere but the technics used to solve it were obscure to me as I didn't learn them yet. And I was given this question in middle school so I think it should be possible using basic math, but I still don't know how. The question is in the title but I'll rewrite it:
$x$ and $y$ are two real numbers such that:
$1 \leq x^2 + y^2 - xy \leq 2$
Show that: $\frac{2}{9} \leq x^4 + y^4 \leq 8$
Any help is really appreciated. Btw the problem is posted here as well as I said [How can I prove that $2/9<x^4+y^4<8$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145506/how-can-i-prove-that-2-9x4y48)

Comment: If you have seen the identical question on this site before then please add a link to that older question.

Comment: What happens if you write this equation in polar coordinates?

Comment: Oh sorry for that, here's the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145506/how-can-i-prove-that-2-9x4y48

Comment: And for the polar coordinates, I don't know what these are as I'm in middle school

Comment: Here is another iteration of this question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2543012/proving-a-given-inequality-frac29x4y48

Comment: But in this second literarion, the question hasn't been answered

Comment: This might help. Set $a=x^2+y^2$ and $b= x y$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=u+v$ and $y=u-v$, then the condition gives
$$1\leq u^2+3v^2\leq 2$$
and the inequality to be proved is equivalent to
$$\frac{1}{9}\leq u^4+v^4+6u^2v^2\leq 4$$
which can be easily proved by $u^4+v^4+6u^2v^2\geq \frac{(u^2+3v^2)^2}{9}$ and $u^4+v^4+6u^2v^2\leq (u^2+3v^2)^2$

Comment: But why are u letting x= u+v and y=u-v? Aren't x and y different numbers and have no relation?

Comment: It's just an ad hoc change of variables that happens to make the formula simpler. It tates like to represent a bunch of numbers (2 numbers here) with their average and variance.